# how to fix badly formatted Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

let us suppose we have  following dataset
[Ram Price](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python/master/data/ram_price.csv)

i have read  this dataset using following command

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python/master/data/ram_price.csv')
```

but  when i  displayed first few items using command

```
print(data.head())
```

it showed me  following result

```
  Unnamed: 0    date        price
0           0  1957.0  411041792.0
1           1  1959.0   67947725.0
2           2  1960.0    5242880.0
3           3  1965.0    2642412.0
4           4  1970.0     734003.0
```

please help me how to fix this? when i tried  drop by Unnamed , it showed me that there is no column Unnamed, how to fix it?

Comment: `df = df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'])` should work

Comment: it gives me following error : 
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the index column, you can select set the index column with an integer index like so :

```
df = pd.read_csv(
'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python/master/data/ram_price.csv'
,index_col=[0])

print(df.head(5))
     date        price
0  1957.0  411041792.0
1  1959.0   67947725.0
2  1960.0    5242880.0
3  1965.0    2642412.0
4  1970.0     734003.0
```

Comment: could you explain me a bit more please to know about this

Comment: what does mean index_col=[0]?

Comment: @datodatuashvili `index_col=[0]` is to mention pandas to use your first column as index of the Dataframe.

Comment: thanks guys for your helps and  happy new year  , i forgot to say this at the begining

Comment: @datodatuashvili Read the Pandas documentation.

Comment: @datodatuashvili glad to have helped, sorry I had to leave for dinner right when I posted this (:

Answer (score 1):

You need to drop a column with entire name.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python/master/data/ram_price.csv')

print(data.columns) #print all the columns in the dataframe
#Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'date', 'price'], dtype='object')

data = data.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis =1) #axis=` specifies to drop column
print(data.head())

#     date        price
#0  1957.0  411041792.0
#1  1959.0   67947725.0
#2  1960.0    5242880.0
#3  1965.0    2642412.0
#4  1970.0     734003.0
```